# How do I fix VSCode autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure what happened but VSCode will not autocomplete for me anymore. In the past, if I were to type in 'div' it would allow me to hit 'Enter' or 'Tab' and autocomplete the div for me. But now it just shows other random code that starts with a 'D'. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Shown code completions]

I've un-abled and re-enabled the Javascript > Suggestions > Autocomplete setting in VSCode settings and that didn't work. I also installed Javascript (ES6) Code Snippets extension per someone else's suggestion here on stack overflow but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is this an html or jsx file?

Comment: It is a jsx file

Comment: Try typing `<div` ?

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + Shift + P on VSCode

then you search for user or settings, and open the (JSON) option

into the JSON, try to paste this:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

good luck, bro

**Edit 1:**

You can try to add this too:

```
"files.associations": {"*html":"html"},
```